# How to add double click event in scanbd for ix500 scanner

Tags: linux

I need to add double click scan button event for fujitsu ix500 scanner. But I cannot find there has double click event in scanbd project.  Is there anyone meet problem?

Comment: see also https://superuser.com/questions/1305301/initiate-scan-from-fujitsu-ix500-to-linux-over-usb/1385521#1385521